# how else do i save integer value into sql database from tkinter entry box

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

When I run this code:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO marks(maths,english,science) VALUES(?,?,?)",(int(mth.get()),int(eng.get()),int(scn.get())))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

How else do i save integer value into sql database from tkinter entry box?

Comment: Hi Shruteerupa Patnaik, welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us help you, could you give us a [mre]? For example, what is the value of `mth`, `eng``or `scn`? Can you modify your question with your additional question?

Comment: The error is telling you what's wrong: you're trying to convert an empty string to an integer. Your first step is to get the values and convert them in a separate step so you can see which ones are the empty string, and then be prepared to write code to handle that condition.